# pasar el query de un dataSearch que seleccione de la búsqueda suggest al screen anterior que hay textfield poner resultado como textController

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, searchview, content-provider, bloc

en un datasearch me arroja los resultados del query y me crea un listTile segun lo que escriba este listatile se ha seleccionado y pone en query lo que quiero es que un textfield sea su controller escuche ese cambio lo ponga en su textfield controller

es lo que he realizado pero lo pone en el decorate labelText

```
TextField(
                onTap: () async {
                  final selectedInstitute = await showSearch(
                    context: context,
                    delegate: DataSearch(),
                  );

                  if (selectedInstitute == null) {
                    print('no se obtuvieron datos');
                    return selectedInstitute;
                  } else {
                    selectedSchool = selectedInstitute;
                    setState(() {});
                    return selectedSchool;
                  }
```

aqui muestro el resultado pero no como texto de controller

```
 decoration: InputDecoration(
 labelText: (selectedSchool != null)
                      ? selectedSchool.nombre
                      : 'Institucion',
```

luego en el DataSeach class

```
return FutureBuilder(
...
...
..
 final instiList = snapshot.data;
        final result = instiList.where(
          (element) => element.nombre.toLowerCase().contains(
                query.toLowerCase().substring(0, query.length),
              ),
        );


return ListView.builder(
itemBuilder: (context, index) {

final matchResult = result
                .map(
                  (e) => _listarResultado(context, e),
                )
                .toList();
if (matchResult.isEmpty) {
              return Container();
            }
 return matchResult[index];
```

aun no he usado majeadores de estado pero los estoy haciendo con provider

Answer (score 0):

se debe inicializar el text editing controller y con ella el init state par que cuando este se encuentre escuchando.

```
 void initState() {
    _textController = TextEditingController(text: prefs.school);

    _textController.addListener(schoolBloc.instanciaInsti(selectedSchool));

    super.initState();
  }
```